# Showing an event as "free" using ical4j

Tags: java, icalendar, ical4j

I am trying to generate an event invitation that is sent via E-Mail. Everything works so far. The only problem is that it is not shown as free. The standard is "conditional" (or whatever the third option in Outlook is, I can't switch mine to English currently) but I want it to be on free as standard so the event doesn't block other events. What is the way to do so?
My ics looks like this currently:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//myProdId
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20210721T122442Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210721
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20210722
SUMMARY:test
CLASS:PRIVATE
UID:20210721142442216-uidGen@fe80:0:0:0:dd32:894f:88da:fde6%wlan0
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
CREATED:20210721T122443Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20210721T122443Z
LOCATION:
ATTENDEE;CN=Test Client;RSVP=FALSE:test@test.com
DESCRIPTION:
ORGANIZER;CN=admin:admin@admin.com
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT1H
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: What is the difference between this version and the other version of this entry when you mark it in your own outlook as free? I'm sure for 80 percent that is just an issue of localisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the TRANSP property. It has two options: opaque is for events that block out time, transparent does not.

https://ical4j.github.io/docs/ical4j/api/3.0.26/net/fortuna/ical4j/model/property/Transp.html

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!